# php cant insert array data into database

Tags: php

the sql :

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_detail WHERE size = $order_size AND product_id = $order_detail_product_id');
```

the code:

```
$order_detail_product_id = $_POST['order']['product_id'];
$order_size = $_POST['order']['size'];
```

html:

```
<?php foreach ($it as $e) { >?
      <input type="text" name="order[product_id][]" value="<?php echo  $e[0]; ?>">
      <input type="text" name="order[size][]" value="<?php echo  $e[3]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

why that's can't work. the error is array to string conversion

Comment: Please edit your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424764/php-array-to-string-conversion) instead of posting a new question.

Comment: sorry i had to change my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424764/php-array-to-string-conversion. one more, im sorry

Comment: What is $it? What does $db->prepare() do? And what are you trying to do with order[product_id][]????

Answer (score -1):

You can't use variables like that inside single quotes in your prepare statement (you'd need double quotes for that to make sense, but it'd still be quite bad and still doesn't make sense cause you're using an array as a string), and also putting the value inside the string you prepare beats the purpose of preparing, you should do:

```
foreach ($order_size as $key => $size):
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_detail WHERE size = ? AND product_id = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $size);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $order_detail_product_id[$key]);
...
endforeach;
```

Or a different query, depending on what you want, which is not easy to guess with what you posted.

Assuming you're using pdo and not mysqli (which would suck).

Comment: the problem is my data is many, if i rename my input as you say, thats not an array data. im sorry for my bad english

Comment: yes, I missed the foreach, in which case you still want to select where in, but anyway, your query seems to have a weird purpose, what's the point of it, what are you trying to select?